# Use stream instead of snprintf

Tags: c++, c

I'm not fairly familiar in C++ stream API and I want to convert a C code using stream in C++,

```
char sHex[20] = {0};
int numid = 2;

snprintf( sHex, sizeof(sHex) - 1, "%X", numId );
```

Comment: By the way, a plain old `sizeof(sHex)` will do for `snprintf()`. You don't need to explicitly manage for the null terminator yourself.

Comment: Don't use `snprintf` unless you don't care about a terminating zero. It's **not** designed to provide the buffer overrun semantics that security types worry about. If you want to go this route, use `sprintf_s`, which was designed for that job.

Comment: @PeteBecker `snprintf` (in Standard C and Standard C++) guarantees to terminate the buffer, unless buffer size was `0`. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
stringstream ss;
ss << uppercase << hex << numId;
string res = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Understanding C++ Streams and Stream Buffers](https://web.archive.org/web/20120624033115/http://www.dyn-lab.com/articles/c-streams.html) it may help you, like as helped me.